# Yii2: display dates in user time zone

Tags: php, date, yii, yii2

In my DB I store all `datetime` fields in **UTC format**. Also, I have the ability to change default time zone by users. Each user can have own time zone, **different from UTC**.

How shall I display all model `datetime` fields in this case?

I have an idea. To do this action for each ActiveRecord model:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    $this->on(ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_FIND, function($event) {

        $this->created_date = (new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone("Europe/Kiev")))->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    });
}
```

But I'm not sure it's the best way for big amount of models...

Comment: added an answer see if it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

if the dates are stored in `UTC` why not append the string UTC along the time and display it

```
$time = strtotime($this->created_at.' UTC');
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

Your code will look like this

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    $this->on(ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_FIND, function($event) {
        $time = strtotime($model->create_at.' UTC');
        $this->created_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);

    });
}
```

if I would do it I would just create a separate `Helper` and use it to display the date in the local format rather than `EVENT_AFTER_FIND`

Another alternative is to use this [**`Extension`**](http://demos.krajee.com/datecontrol-demo)

Answer (score 0):

Search for **frontend/config/main.php**

Try putting in

```
return [
...
'components' => [
...
```

a FORMATTER part like

```
        'formatter' => [
          'dateFormat' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
          'datetimeFormat' => 'dd/MM/yyyy H:i:s',
          'timeFormat' => 'H:i:s',
          'locale' => 'it-IT',            
          'decimalSeparator' => ',',
          'thousandSeparator' => '.',
          'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
          'numberFormatterSymbols' => [
               NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL => '€',
           ],            
           'timeZone' => 'Europe/Rome',
         ],
```

Set your parameters like TimeZone, Currency, etc...

NB: I dont remember but maybe the NumberFormatter part need some other setup so delete the numberFormatterSymbols part if it give to you an error

Comment: Thanks but I don't use the formatter when I display dates in my views.